# Image is not added when creating a draft blog post with Wix API

Tags: velo

I am sending a post request using Wix API. I specify everything when sending the post request. It adds everything except heroimage. How can I make it add heroimage?

body content of my post request

```html
{
  "draftPost": {
    "title": "abc1",
    "categoryIds": ["56a35b26-7c21-4208-b907-e07fd7fe192e"],
    "heroImage": {
      "id": "b46b9a_31bfc3b9a02a41c487bcd687d98186ba~mv2.png",
      "url": "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/b46b9a_31bfc3b9a02a41c487bcd687d98186ba~mv2.png"
    },
    "richContent": {
      "nodes": [
        {
            "type": "PARAGRAPH",
            "id": "",
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "type": "IMAGE",
                    "id": "",
                    "nodes": [],
                    "imageData": {
                        "type": "SITE",
                        "siteData": {
                            "id": "b46b9a_31bfc3b9a02a41c487bcd687d98186ba~mv2.png",
                            "url": "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/b46b9a_31bfc3b9a02a41c487bcd687d98186ba~mv2.png"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "paragraphData": {
                "textStyle": {"textAlignment": "CENTER"},
                "indentation": 0
            }
        },
        {
          "type": "PARAGRAPH",
          "id": "foo",
          "nodes": [
            {
              "type": "TEXT",
              "id": "foo2",
              "nodes": [],
              "textData": {
                "text": "This is a paragraph of text.",
                "decorations": []
              }
            }
          ],
          "paragraphData": {
            "textStyle": {"textAlignment": "AUTO"},
            "indentation": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "PARAGRAPH",
          "id": "foo3",
          "nodes": [
            {
              "type": "TEXT",
              "id": "foo4",
              "nodes": [],
              "textData": {
                "text": "This is another paragraph of text.",
                "decorations": []
              }
            }
          ],
          "paragraphData": {
            "textStyle": {"textAlignment": "AUTO"},
            "indentation": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "PARAGRAPH",
          "id": "foo5",
          "nodes": [
            {
              "type": "TEXT",
              "id": "foo6",
              "nodes": [],
              "textData": {
                "text": "This is yet another paragraph of text.",
                "decorations": []
              }
            }
          ],
          "paragraphData": {
            "textStyle": {"textAlignment": "AUTO", "paddingTop": "20px"},
            "indentation": 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "publish": false
}
```

I was expecting a heroimage to be added when I sent a post request using Wix API, but it was not added.

I haven't been able to solve this problem related to Wix API for 1 week, can you please help?